# Is it possible to set the value for an HTML form input by reading values of other inputs with PHP?

Tags: php, forms

I am working on a prescription order form, and the client wants to be able to enter the quantity of medication taken per dose, the frequency of dose, and the duration of this dosage schedule, and then have the results of those fields used to calculate the quantity of medication needed. For example, if they selected "2 pills", "3 times per day", and "14 days", they want the **quantity** input to be set to 2*3*14 = "84" .

The entering of the **quantity per dose**, **frequency of dose**, and **duration of doses** are all done with `<select>`, so there is a strict set of values that can be entered.

Is there a way that I can grab the values of quantity per dose, frequency of dose, and duration of doses with PHP **before the form is submitted**, and set the value of the quantity field on the fly based upon those values?

Here is the HTML for the section of the form where the fields mentioned above are located.

```
<label for="qtyperdose">Qty per Dose</label>
<select id="qtyperdose">
    <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
    <option value="0.5">1/2</option>
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<label for="frequency">Frequency Of Dose</label>
<select id="frequency">
    <option value="twice per day">twice per day</option>
    <option value="3 times per day">3 times per day</option>
    <option value="once per day" selected>once per day</option>
</select>
<label for="duration">Duration</label>
<select id="duration">
    <option value="7">7 days</option>
    <option value="14" selected>14 days</option>
    <option value="21">21 days</option>
</select>
<label for="total_quantity">Quantity: </label> 
<input type="number" id="quantity" max="100"> <!-- Default needs to be calculated from qtyperdose * frequency * duration -->
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server so any calculations you do in PHP will be on the server. You **could** fire off an ajax request to get PHP to do the calculations ( requires Javascript ) or do the calculations and update the display completely in Javascript. The wording `"on the fly"` suggests these as preferable to a regular form submission - it is fairly simple javascript

Answer (score -1):

The form elements should really have names rather than just ID attributes if you intend to submit these to the server for final processing so the following has been modified accordingly.

Some rudimentary Javascript that uses a `delegated change event handler` to process each of the 3 select menus - the name/value are added to a global object, when that global object has 3 property/value pairs the calculation is done and the result displayed in the total.

```js
let inputs={};
let total=document.querySelector('#quantity');

document.addEventListener('change',e=>{
  inputs[ e.target.name ]=Number( e.target.value );

  if( Object.keys( inputs ).length==3 ){
    let result=Object.values( inputs ).reduce( ( a, b )=>a * Number(b) );
    if( result > total.getAttribute('max') ){
      alert('Thats umpossible!');
      return;
    }
      
     total.value=result;
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="qtyperdose">Qty per Dose</label>
<select name='qty' id="qtyperdose">
  <option hidden selected disabled>Quantity per dose
    <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
    <option value="0.5">1/2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<label for="frequency">Frequency Of Dose</label>
<select name='frequency' id="frequency">
  <option hidden selected disabled>Frequency
    <option value="2">twice per day</option>
    <option value="3">3 times per day</option>
    <option value="1">once per day</option>
</select>

<label for="duration">Duration</label>
<select name='duration' id="duration">
  <option hidden selected disabled>Duration
    <option value="7">7 days</option>
    <option value="14">14 days</option>
    <option value="21">21 days</option>
</select>

<label for="total_quantity">Quantity: </label> 
<input type="number" id="quantity" max="100" />
```

Answer (score -1):

As u say:

> **before the form is submitted**

Only using php its not possible.
that said, you need javascript.

```js
     function calcquantity(){
      qtyperdose = document.getElementById("qtyperdose").value;
      frequency = document.getElementById("frequency").value;
      duration = document.getElementById("duration").value;
      total = qtyperdose * frequency * duration;
      console.log(total);
      document.getElementById("quantity").value = total;
    
    }
    calcquantity();
```

```html
    <label for="qtyperdose">Qty per Dose</label>
    <select id="qtyperdose" name="qtyperdose" onchange="calcquantity()">
        <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
        <option value="0.5">1/2</option>
        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <label for="frequency">Frequency Of Dose</label>
    <select id="frequency" name="frequency" onchange="calcquantity()">
    
        <option value="2">twice per day</option>
        <option value="3">3 times per day</option>
        <option value="1" selected>once per day</option>
    </select>
    <label for="duration">Duration</label>
    <select id="duration" name="duration" onchange="calcquantity()">
    
        <option value="7">7 days</option>
        <option value="14" selected>14 days</option>
        <option value="21">21 days</option>
    </select>
    <label for="total_quantity">Quantity: </label> 
    <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" max="100"> <!-- Default needs to be calculated from qtyperdose * frequency * duration -->
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).